# Running jenkins gives "package org.junit does not exist"

Tags: java, ant, junit, jenkins

Can any one please help me with that error?

```
build-project:
     [echo] AntProject: /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/build.xml
    [javac] Compiling 2 source files to /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/bin
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/src/com/moi/test/junit/MaClasseTest.java:3: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import static org.junit.Assert.*;
    [javac]                        ^
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/src/com/moi/test/junit/MaClasseTest.java:5: package org.junit does not exist
    [javac] import org.junit.Test;
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/src/com/moi/test/junit/MaClasseTest.java:9: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Test
    [javac] location: class com.moi.test.junit.MaClasseTest
    [javac]     @Test
    [javac]      ^
    [javac] /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/src/com/moi/test/junit/MaClasseTest.java:12: cannot find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : method assertTrue(boolean)
    [javac] location: class com.moi.test.junit.MaClasseTest
    [javac]              assertTrue(MaClasse.additioner(2,2) == 4); 
    [javac]              ^
    [javac] 4 errors

BUILD FAILED /root/.jenkins/jobs/Ant/workspace/build.xml:35: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Does it only happen in Jenkins, or does it happen also when you start the build from the command line using Ant? Maybe this question will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792445/running-ant-build-gives-package-org-junit-does-not-exist

Answer (score 3):

it seems you forgot to make junit library available in your classparh

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but can you tell me how can I do it?

Comment: download junit jar from [here](https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/downloads) , add it to your classpath. for further information check [this](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-JARs-to-Project-Build-Paths-in-Eclipse-(Java))

Comment: how is this configured on the jenkins server?

Comment: @sim you should provide it in your app runtime classpath, if not under controll put it to server's lib

Answer (score 1):

My solution :

- Download junit.jar
- In the projet.properties file, find the line "javac.test.classpath=\" and add at the end
    /your/path/to/junit-4.10.jar
- you can test locally to see if it works
- push on github
- build on jenkins and voila it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a compilation classpath to javac, which includes junit.jar.

Check the `<classpath>` tag inside `<javac>` for one way to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because I accidentally put the failing *JUnit test* Java source file to location `src/main/java/...` instead of the correct `src/test/java/...`.

My IDE *Eclipse* didn't complain about missing imports and would happily run tests from that file while it was located at `src/main/java/...` — while Jenkins would abort building, and therefore testing.

Moving the problematic file to the correct location, `src/test/java/...`, resolved my issue.