# Action Bar Sherlock Compiling Error

Tags: java, android, macos, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock

I am trying to import a program file for android app. But having issues with setting up ActionBarSherlock giving me errors. I am using a MAC with IntelliJ 12 CE, Android SDK, Java, and Action Bar Sherlock. How do I set it up to not get errors?

```
java: /library-projects/actionbar-sherlock-4.2.0/test/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/ManifestParsingTest.java:3: package org.junit does not exist

java: /library-projects/actionbar-sherlock-4.2.0/test/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/ManifestParsingTest.java:6: package org.hamcrest does not exist

java: /library-projects/actionbar-sherlock-4.2.0/test/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/ManifestParsingTest.java:6: static import only from classes and interfaces

java: /library-projects/actionbar-sherlock-4.2.0/test/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/ManifestParsingTest.java:7: package org.junit does not exist

java: /library-projects/actionbar-sherlock-4.2.0/test/com/actionbarsherlock/internal/ManifestParsingTest.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Test
location: class com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ManifestParsingTest
```

Comment: You really need to say *what* the errors are, and show your code.

Comment: We can't guess what errors you are getting.. :/

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/6328550/786337

Comment: Thanks for the help Tarun I was missing the JUnit file I added it to the class path works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell intellJ not to run tests:

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> actionbarsherlock -> Source
```

Remove tests from the right column.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having problem on importing ActionBarSherlock to your project then you can import it this way
Right click your project --> click on android ---> click on add and add the actionbarsherlock and click on ok and then apply and again ok if it gives the jar mismatch error delete the android supportv4 library in your project and then clean it.

Answer (score 0):

This is applicable for Intellij Idea

```
File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Import/New Module ->
```

Select the base directory of action bar sherlock library.

Comment: I have tried this but nothing is working! In the project under library projects it shows actionbarsherlock 4.2.0 but I still get error. I added it to the google API 4.0 and other ones like 2.2 etc. still nothing.