# Cannot find package org.junit when compiling java file in command prompt

Tags: java, ant, junit

Whenever I run my java file in command prompt, I keep getting errors saying:

```
error: package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
```

This also gives errors on symbols like "@Test".

Here's my java file code:

```
package org.example.antbook.junit; 
//import required JUnit4 classes:
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Test;

public class SimpleTest
{
    @Test    
    public void testSomething() 
    {
        assertTrue("MULTIPLICATION???", 4 == (2 * 2));
    }
}
```

I believe it is something to do with importing junit-4.10.jar which I have already imported, but I may be missing something.
Is there a solution to this?

Comment: this may be helpful :http://stackoverflow.com/a/1792686/1862502

Answer (score 0):

You need to put "junit.jar" on the classpath when you compile and then when you run the class.

Please refer to the manual entries for the [`java`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) and [`javac`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) commands, and also to the page on [setting the classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

If you are building from the command line using Ant, then you need to make sure that your "build.xml" sets the compilation classpath correctly.

---

You will also need to add `import` statements to import any Junit 4 annotations that you use.  But you need to address the "package org.junit does not exist" issue first.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and added the Junit file path to the classpath and that solved it. Be aware that User Environment variable takes precedence over the system environment variable when the EV exists in both.