# Unable to build on ant 1.9.4

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am trying to build test cases by using ant 1.9.4. I can build them with 1.9.0. But getting errors with 1.9.4 (Seems like it is not configuring junit jar).
This is how I'm mentioning path of junit jar file.

```
<property name="junit.home"   location="${basedir}/lib"/>
<filelist dir="${junit.home}"   files="junit4.8.2.jar"/>
```

NOTE: I'm able to build by using amt 1.9.0.

Errors which I'm getting

```
package org.junit does not exist
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add junit.jar to your ant classpath.
Simply copy the junit.jar file to the ${ANT_HOME}/lib folder.

Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792445/running-ant-build-gives-package-org-junit-does-not-exist).