# Jenkins Project Can't Find Packages; build-project target fails

Tags: java, xml, jenkins, ivy, build.xml

My project compiles and runs on my local machine, but on Jenkins the build-project target fails to compile due to being unable to find my packages. I can see that the jars that I think I need are in my `./bin/` folder, so I anticipate there is something about classpaths or my build-project target that is causing the issue.

**build.xml -> build-project:**

```
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}" />
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" includeantruntime="false" source="${source}" target="${target}">
        <src path="src" />
        <classpath refid="sierraMadreTestScripts.classpath" />
    </javac>
</target>
```

**error message excerpt on Jenkins:**

```
build-project:
 [echo] sierraMadreTestScripts: /data/builds/jenkins/workspace/build.xml
[javac] Compiling 1 source file to /data/builds/jenkins/workspace/bin
[javac] /data/builds/jenkins/workspace/src/testScripts/TranslatorWorkflow.java:3: error: package org.junit does not exist
[javac] import static org.junit.Assert.fail;
[javac]                        ^
```

I can post my full build.xml, ivy.xml, ivysettings.xml, or whatever else would be necessary to diagnose the problem. Sorry if this is really basic; Ivy is still rather arcane to me. I'm running my local project within Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of your problem is outlined in the following question:

[Running ant build gives "package org.junit does not exist"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1792445/running-ant-build-gives-package-org-junit-does-not-exist)

In short IDEs like Eclipse automatically put junit in your classpath..... Ivy is actually designed to help solve this problem and used properly it can be used to manage all aspects of your project's classpaths.

Without access to your build logic I must guess, but it looks like you're building both code and tests using a single javac? You have a classpath called "sierraMadreTestScripts.classpath", the next question is how is this created and managed. Your question implies that ivy is somehow involved :-)